# Books like "English Grammar in use" for the German language

Tags: grammar, book, reference

```
      "English Grammar in Use" - Cambridge University Press
```

is amazing.  Is there any similar books for the German language?

[Update]:
"English Grammar in Use" is amazing because each unit spans one page, one page for the grammar and the other is for exercises.

Comment: It's hard to answer this if you do not specify why you think "English Grammar in Use" is amazing. One standard grammar book is [Duden: Die Grammatik](http://www.amazon.de/Duden-04-Die-Grammatik-Unentbehrlich/dp/3411040483/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1322053691&sr=8-1)

Comment: You may also want to have a look at the editions for schools [Schülerduden Grammatik](http://www.duden.de/produkt/Grammatik-05636-1) or [Duden Schulgrammatik](http://www.duden.de/produkt/Duden---Schulgrammatik-extra---Deutsch-71993-8). However I personally have no idea if they are any good. If somebody can recommend them, please write an answer!

Answer (score 5):

You can try [Lehr- und Übungsbuch der deutschen Grammatik](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3190072558). I'm not sure if it has your favorite format of one page explanation, one page exercises, though.

But it contains concise and succinct explanations and exercises (maybe a little bit scattered). The exercises are divided in small parts providing an easy step by step approach. I use a similar book from Hueber-Verlag for learning Spanish and I am very pleased with that book. But I haven't used this German grammar book myself.

Sadly I haven't found a "Power Grammatik" book from the same publisher for German, because this series uses exactly the format you ask for. Maybe they publish one in the near future. An email to the publisher to push them couldn't hurt ;)

Comment: I have been learning German for about 10 years now and from my experience I can tell that this is the only book that is somehow comparable to the Essential Grammar series.

Answer (score 5):

It has not the same format as the mentioned English "Grammar in Use", but **[Hammer's German Grammar and Usage](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1444120166)** seems to be a good book. It got 29 five-stars reviews (out of 30 reviews).

- Paperback: 600 pages
- Publisher: Hodder Education Publishers; 5th Edition edition (July 10, 2011)
- ISBN-10: 1444120166
- ISBN-13: 978-1444120165

Also available from McGraw-Hill as a companion to this book: **[Practicing German Grammar: A Workbook, Second Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1444120174)**.

Answer (score 3):

Modern German Grammar: A Practical Guide, Third Edition

Ruth Whittle, John Klapper, Katharina Glöckel, Bill Dodd and Christine Eckhard-Black

It is concise (111 pages) and extremely thorough.

One can also purchase a small workbook for practicing (üben).

Answer (score 3):

**Übungsgrammatik für die Grundstufe**:

- http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/3922989705
- http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/3922989713

**Übungsgrammatik für die Mittelstufe**:

- http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/3922989519
- http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/3922989527

**Übungen zum Wortschatz der deutschen Schriftsprache**:

- http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/3922989616
- http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/3922989624

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for exactly the same kind of grammar book and I think I found it: It is called *Grammatik – ganz klar* by Hueber. It is all in German but it isn’t difficult to follow, altough a dictionary comes in handy sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

[Hammer's German Grammar and Usage:](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1444120166)

> Long trusted as the most comprehensive, up-to-date, and user-friendly grammar available, Hammer's German Grammar and Usage provides students and teachers with a complete guide to German as it is written and spoken today. It includes clear and concise descriptions of all the main grammatical features of German, highlighting the most common forms of usage, both formal and informal. The new edition includes updated modern-day examples, discusses words from English roots in current use such as "zertweeten," and features an entirely new chapter on pronunciation. Its combination of reference grammar and manual of current usage will prove invaluable to students and teachers.

Also, by clicking on its picture in amazon, you can see its contents and a few pages. It has got 29 customer reviews as well.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for exactly the same kind of grammar books too, and I found:

- [Klipp und Klar – Übungsgrammatik Grundstufe](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Klipp-Und-Klar-Ubungsgrammatik-Grundstufe/dp/3126753221)
- [Klipp und Klar – Übungsgrammatik Mittelstufe](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Klipp-Und-Klar-Ubungsgrammatik-Mittelstufe/dp/3126753175/)

These books are all in German and the first of them has one page for the grammar and the other for exercises.