# Gute Grammatik der deutschen Sprache gesucht, die für englischsprachige Lerner geschrieben ist

Tags: book

Ich suche eine wirklich gute Grammatik des Deutschen in englischer Sprache, denn aus der Außenperspektive und im Sprachvergleich werden oft Probleme sichtbar, die einem nicht bewusst werden, solange man nur 'im eigenen Saft schmort'. Kann jemand dazu gute Empfehlungen abgeben? Leider kenne ich mich ja mit der englischen Sprache nicht so gut aus, obwohl ich's (gelesen) ganz passabel verstehe, daher kenne ich auch entsprechende Grammatiken nicht. Am liebsten wären mir Empfehlungen, bei deren Studium sich für Euch Aha-Erlebnisse ergeben hatten, die aufgrund ihrer Erklärungsansätze oder in der Art der Präsentation als neuartig - aber nicht oberflächlich-modisch zu verstehen - oder als innovativ zu bezeichnen wären.

[Hier einen passenden Tag zu finden, ist nicht möglich. Vielleicht ist dieses Forum nicht geeignet, um eine solche Frage zu stellen.]

Comment: related (in English): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/books-like-english-grammar-in-use-for-the-german-language

Answer (score 1):

[Das hier](https://www.amazon.de/Reading-German-Course-Reference-Grammar/dp/0198700202) (Reading German: A Course Book and Reference Grammar von Waltraud Coles und Bill Dodd) wird an der Harvard University als Grammatik für die Fortgeschrittenenkurse, in denen Kant und Mann gelesen wird, verwendet - kann also nicht ganz schlecht sein.

Interessant ist, dass das Buch ein *Versuch der Anleitung zum Leseverständnis* ist - Also keine platt heruntergebetete Grammatik, sondern möglicherweise genau, was du suchst.

Comment: Hört sich interessant an - werd' danach Ausschau halten, danke dir.

Answer (score -1):

Guck dir mal [Hammer's German Grammar](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1444120166) an.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21787)

Comment: The important part here is the name **Hammer's German Grammar**. That's a book you can and should actually buy, if you find the linked copy useful.

Comment: Ah, I see, someone removed the link to the preview, and made this answer less useful.

Comment: Ein, zwei Argumente, wieso Du es empfiehlst, würden dennoch nicht schaden.

Comment: @Janka: eine "Vorschau", die ein ganzes Buch in einem 561-Seiten langen PDF  zur Verfügung stellt geht gar nicht. Das Buch ist ja nicht Public Domain. Mit dem Amazon Link erhält man aber ebenfalls eine Vorschau ("look inside") und geichzeitig tun wir Stack Exchange über den Affiliate Bonus noch etwas Gutes.

Comment: Wenn du genauer reingeguckt hättest, hättest du gemerkt, dass die von mir verlinkte Version absichtliche Fehler enthält. Sowohl Layoutfehler als auch inhaltliche. Es handelt sich dabei also nicht um das fertige Buch, sondern um einen Vorabzug irgendeiner alten Auflage. Zum Bewerten des Inhalts reicht es, wer danach lernt wird eher böse auf die Schnauze fallen.

Comment: Deinem Kommentar entnehme ich, dass man nicht beurteilen kann, ob dies die Frage beantwortet, ohne dem Link zu folgen.

Comment: Das ist dann aber ein Mangel in der Frage, die nach Meinungen fragt.

Comment: Nuja, ich wollte eine Empfehlung, und da genügt mir persönlich der Titel, die Meinung bilde ich mir dann selber. Danke Janka.