# Is there a complete German grammar book?

Tags: reference

I am looking for a complete German grammar book, where everything would be explained for all levels in English. At the moment I am finding a German grammar book with exercises or German grammar for specific levels. But I would prefer complete German grammar for all levels, the best with detailed descriptions (not the short books using a lot of grammar-specific terms - I am not the youngest to remember what such grammar terms mean, so I would prefer a bigger book, where everything is explained in detail.)

PS: I have seen some PDFs in [another thread](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/3069/1696) and even though they have a nice structure, they don't mention everything. The "German grammar in use" style is good for practicing grammar, but I am missing a reference book (preferably in English), where I can find answers to different grammatical questions I could have.

Comment: This question needs more details. Can you read German proficiently or are you trying to learn German? If it is the latter, why would you need an Eierlegende Wollmilchsau instead of a learners textbook / concise handbook.

Comment: @vectory I cannot read German, so I would prefer the book to be written in English. Yes, I am trying to learn. Why? Perhaps I have a different learning style. Is that a problem?

Comment: @Juandev: like every other language German has levels of proficiency. You won't need anything else than a beginners book if you are a beginner (like you are, if you can't read German, as you say.) i.e. for someone learning addition and subtraction a book covering differential equations might be confusing and counterproductive rather than helpful.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/3069/1696) and its answers handling some grammars?

Comment: @guidot I have seen some PDFs of those mentioned and even though they have a nice structure, they don't mention everything. So If I am learning the use of numerals in Years, one book tells you part, the other one tells you another part and it's pretty time-consuming to open all books and all websites to get comprehensive information on a certain topic. The "German grammar in use" style is good for practicing grammar, but I am missing a reference book, where I can find answers to different grammatical questions I could have.

Answer (score 3):

You want

- *Hammer's German Grammar and Usage* by Martin Durell.

Highly recommended if you are prepared to be confronted with all the details. There are no simplifications in this exposition.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Martin Durrell: *Using German*; see [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511840777). This book contains an immense amount of grammar and many practical examples.

Comment: Nice book, but e.g. for numbers and years there is nothing. I have seen similar books elsewhere, so the question is if they are not books about differences in grammar between English and German, that they don't contain certain features.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any grammar book written in English. But there is one in German, which I can recommend if you like grammar:
It is called ["Grammatik aktiv"](https://www.cornelsen.de/reihen/grammatik-aktiv-deutsch-als-fremdsprache-120002420000), the publisher is "Cornelsen".
It consists of 2 books, each comes together with a CD.

Answer (score 0):

Try out

"em: Übungsgrammatik, Wiederholung der Grundstufe Mittelstufe"

This is very popular among the students preparing for TestDaF.

Answer (score 0):

For something much shorter and simpler try TES Resources, author Lenz, where you will find "The Ultimate German Grammar" and related material